# My rep's under 300 here. Could tags be added?

Tags: support

I've posted [How can I get Yoast SEO under Wordpress to display multilevel heirarchical breadcrumbs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122787/how-can-i-get-yoast-seo-under-wordpress-to-display-multilevel-heirarchical-bread), but was not allowed to create tags "breadcrumb" and "yoast-seo".

Could someone with sufficient privileges create those tags and assign them to my post?

Answer (score 6):

Tags for [breadcrumbs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breadcrumbs) and [yoast](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yoast) already existed, so I edited your question to add them.

I'm not certain if they weren't appearing or were just missed, but normally you'd just type the first couple of letters of the tag in the `Tags` form box and they should appear in a drop-down list below that so you can click to select them. I suppose if JavaScript was disabled or blocked in your browser that might prevent them from showing up, but likely much of the site wouldn't work very well either...so that likely wasn't the issue.